# How does Python know I want to double number I did not define? (Beginner)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = 10
def double(y):
    return 2 * x
print(double(x))
```

Output is 20
As far as I know, it should return None because in function "double" I double x which is undefined that block.

Comment: If the variable isn't defined in the function, it searches the containing scopes.

Comment: If you remove `x=10` and use `print(double(10))` you'll get the NameError you "wanted". Nice first question.

Answer (score 2):

x is defined outside of the function scope as a global variable that is also available in the function

Answer (score 1):

It is because x is a global variable, so when you call double it is just multiplying x by 2 no matter what
if you were to say put

```
x = 10
def double(y):
    return 2 * x
print(double(40))
```

you would still get 20 as you are returning the variable x multiplied by 2.

Comment: It also would not return None it would throw an error because 2 multiplied by None is not possible.